# Android API 11 introduced new components including ListView and GridView in app widgets, is there a way to scroll horizontally in app widgets now?

Tags: android, scroll, widget, android-3.0-honeycomb

I've read in the [Android 3.0 documentation](http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-3.0.html) that it is now possible to use **"several new widget classes for more interactive app widgets on the users Home screen, including: GridView, ListView, StackView, ViewFlipper, and AdapterViewFlipper."**

Is this list exhaustive or can I use for example Gallery with an app widget in the API 11 ?

If not, is there now a way to have a horizontal scrolling area in app widgets ?

Thanks,

Laurent

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can't scroll horizontally in an AppWidget because that would break switching home screens.